# PHP - Regex to change 'surrounding' tag

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a piece of UTF-8 encoded HTML that I need to get one file reference out of, then I need to change it entirely using said file reference.

This is the starting code:

```
&lt;object width=&quot;250&quot; height=&quot;20&quot; data=&quot;player.swf&quot; type=&quot;application/x-shockwave-flash&quot;&gt;
&lt;param name=&quot;data&quot; value=&quot;player.swf&quot; /&gt;
&lt;param name=&quot;flashvars&quot; value=&quot;file=TEST.MP3&quot; /&gt;
&lt;param name=&quot;src&quot; value=&quot;player.swf&quot; /&gt;
&lt;/object&gt;
```

As you can see, it's an object tag that contains a reference to a file, and a flash player.

This is the code that I require:

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="TEST.MP3"&gt;TEST.MP3&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

I've tried getting the file reference out first, then just replacing the object part entirely with an a tag, but this just replaces all object tags and not just the one I need.

The easiest way would be ofcourse to just 'replace' the object tag with an a tag, but I don't know how to do a Regex to find and replace everything 'around' the file you need.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Why is your input HTML-encoded if it's supposed to be literal HTML?

Comment: There are some ü's and ä's that give errors with what I'm working with.

Comment: It would then be better to determine the exact cause of the problem and fix it rather than doing this hack.

Comment: I'm creating an .xml to import in an e-learning backup and the content needs to be UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the surrounding code will be the same in all future cases and only the TEST.MP3 changes you could use the following RegEx that I've tested:

```php
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
$test = '<object width="250" height="20" data="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="data" value="player.swf" />
<param name="flashvars" value="file=TEST.MP3" />
<param name="src" value="player.swf" />
</object>';

echo preg_replace('/^\<object.*\n.*\n.*file\=(.*)\".*\n.*\n.*/mi','<a href="$1">$1</a>',$test);

?>
```

This is working in PHP 5.3.10.

Comment: Thanks mate, works perfectly and all the surrounding code is the same as you mentioned.